# How to prevent DDoS attack with Jax-RS?

Tags: java, jax-rs, wildfly

I've implemented this simple class that handle possible DDoS attack in a Jax-rs Rest-API service.
What do you think about?

```
public static CheckerDDOS getInstance(StatusIPDao statusDao, HttpRequestDao httpRequestDao) {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new CheckerDDOS(statusDao, httpRequestDao);
        new CleanerHTTPRequest(httpRequestDao).setupClean();
    }
    return instance;
}

public void check(String ip, String uri, ContainerRequestContext container) {
    statusIP = statusDao.findByIp(ip);
    if (statusIP != null) {
        if (statusIP.isBlocked()) {
            blockedIP(container);
            return;
        }
        if (statusIP.getnOfRequestsLastMinute() >= LIMIT_REQUEST) {
            rateLimitExceeded(container);
            return;
        }
    } else {
        statusIP = new StatusIP();
        statusIP.setIp(ip);
    }
    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            HttpRequest httpRequest = new HttpRequest();
            httpRequest.setIp(ip);
            httpRequest.setUri(uri);
            httpRequest.setTimestamp(Calendar.getInstance());
            httpRequestDao.store(httpRequest);
            long nOfRequestsLastMinute = httpRequestDao.countByIp(ip);
            statusIP.setnOfRequestsLastMinute(nOfRequestsLastMinute);
            statusDao.store(statusIP);
        }
    }).start();
}

private void blockedIP(ContainerRequestContext container) {
    container.abortWith(Response.status(Status.UNAUTHORIZED).entity("Your IP address has been blocked!").build());
}

private void rateLimitExceeded(ContainerRequestContext container) {
    container.abortWith(Response.status(Status.TOO_MANY_REQUESTS)
            .entity("Too many requests, you're IP has been blocked!").build());
}
```

And this is called in the Filter:

```
String ip = request.getRemoteAddr();
    String uri = info.getPath();
    CheckerDDOS checkerDDOS = CheckerDDOS.getInstance(statusDao, httpRequestDao);
    checkerDDOS.check(ip, uri, container);
```

Answer (score 4):

You could still easily be DDOS'd.  I can come into your server from a blocklist IP 10's of thousands of times a second and now I've DDOS'd your Wildfly and possibly your database.

There are on-server solutions like [mod_ratelimit](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ratelimit.html) and for IP blocklists [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/550356/retrieve-malicious-ip-addresses-from-apache-logs-and-block-them-with-iptables) does it at the O/S level.  But in a clustered environment you now have to maintain that across all machines.

I would say that if you're hosted in a real environment with a real production server you need something like the AWS [WAF](https://aws.amazon.com/waf/) or the equivalent of that in other environments.  Don't reinvent the wheel - there are better ways of doing this that don't require you to maintain it.